# adding symlinks in cmake without using 'make install'

Tags: cmake

I have a bunch of libraries I have to build. For each library I create 3 sym-links. 
I create two symlinks using :

```
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC})
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES SOVERSION ${perception_kit_VERSION})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${Boost_LIBS})
```

But the remaining two are created using :

```
#code for generating symlink. will work with make install
if (CMAKE_HOST_UNIX)
  set (libname_major_minor_patch "lib${PROJECT_NAME}.so.${perception_kit_VERSION_MAJOR}.${perception_kit_VERSION_MINOR}.${perception_kit_VERSION_PATCH}")
  set (libname_major_minor "lib${PROJECT_NAME}.so.${perception_kit_VERSION_MAJOR}.${perception_kit_VERSION_MINOR}")
  set (libname_major "lib${PROJECT_NAME}.so.${perception_kit_VERSION_MAJOR}")
  set (libname "lib${PROJECT_NAME}.so")

  install(CODE "
          EXECUTE_PROCESS (COMMAND ln -sf ${libname_major_minor_patch} ${libname_major_minor}  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH} )
")
  install(CODE "
          EXECUTE_PROCESS (COMMAND ln -sf ${libname_major_minor_patch} ${libname_major}  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH} )
")

endif(CMAKE_HOST_UNIX)
```

The last two are created only when make install is used. Is there a way to make all the sym links without using make install. ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To execute a post-build command, you can use [`add_custom_command(TARGET ...)`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_command)

So in this case, I guess you'd want something like

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ln -sf ${libname_major_minor_patch} ${libname_major_minor}
    COMMAND ln -sf ${libname_major_minor_patch} ${libname_major}
)
```